# How to export object from c to node addon api

Tags: c++, node.js, node-addon-api

I have c++ code wrapped using node-addon-api:

```
Napi::String Method(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info)
{
  Napi::Env env = info.Env();
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm *timeinfo;
  char system_date_buffer[80];
  char iso_date_buffer[80];

  time(&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  strftime(system_date_buffer, 80, "%x", timeinfo);
  string sysDateFormat(system_date_buffer);
  strftime(iso_date_buffer, 80, "%%Y-%m-%d", timeinfo);
  string isoDateFormat(iso_date_buffer);
  return Napi::String::New(env, sysDateFormat);
}
```

**Init:**

```
Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports)
{
  exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "sysDateFormat"), Napi::Function::New(env, Method));
  exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "isoDateFormat"), Napi::Function::New(env, Method));
  return exports;
}
```

How do I return different values or export an object? Above I am returning only

`return Napi::String::New(env, sysDateFormat);`

How do I return `isoDateFormat` also? My idea is to put `sysDateFormat` and `isoDateFormat` in to object and return it but not sure of syntax

Currently I am returning only string

**Update:**

I have used array to store both values but return type is showing compile time error: `no instance of overloaded function "Napi::Array::New" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (Napi::Env, std::string [2])`

```
Napi::Array Method(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info)
{
  Napi::Env env = info.Env();
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm *timeinfo;
  char system_date_buffer[80];
  char iso_date_buffer[80];
  string dateArray [2];

  time(&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  strftime(system_date_buffer, 80, "%x", timeinfo);
  string sysDateFormat(system_date_buffer);
  strftime(iso_date_buffer, 80, "%%Y-%m-%d", timeinfo);
  string isoDateFormat(iso_date_buffer);
  dateArray[0] = sysDateFormat;
  dateArray[1] = iso_date_buffer;
  return Napi::Array::New(env, dateArray); // error here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Object type from Napi api worked!

```
 Napi::Object obj = Napi::Object::New(env);
  obj.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "sysDateFormat"), sysDateFormat);
  obj.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "isoDateFormat"), isoDateFormat);
```

Comment: Can be simplified a bit by passing a string directly, eg. `obj.Set("sysDateFormat", sysDateFormat);`